# Volume of a prism will be max if $\sin \theta$ is?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

> known this picture
>   [image]

How to find the $\sin \theta$ that makes volume max?

My attempt

The volume of prism is $v = \text{base} \cdot x$.

Base is trapezium, area of trapezium = $x\cos \theta \cdot(x + x + x\sin \theta)/2$

Volume will be $x^3\cdot (\cos \theta )\cdot (2 + \sin \theta)/2$

Comment: Area of base need to be divided by 2

Comment: You use terms that does not appear in the drawing

Comment: Differentiate and equate to zero.

Comment: How to differentiate it?

Comment: @Lifeforbetter  How did you obtained those expressions given for  $Area\space for\space base\space$ and $\space Volume$? I assume that $x$ is a length. If $x$ has the dimension  [Length], then the area must have the dimension $\rm{[Length]}^2$.

Comment: Area is trapezium? And volume is base times height?

Comment: I edited the question again to reflect clearly a volume

Comment: ok. but how to find the maximum volume then?